# null space of an n-by-m matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an $n$-by-$m$ ($n>m$) matrix named $J$. I wanted to find its null space so as I used matrix $M$ defined bellow:
$$JM=0\text{, when } M=I-J^\dagger J$$
$J^\dagger$ is the pseudo inverse of $J$.

Now my question is that am I allowed to choose any ($r=m-n$) columns of $M$ as null space of $J$ or not, in the other words, can I be sure that the columns of $M$ are linearly independent?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $J$ is of full rank, the null space is only the 0 vector, isn't ?

Comment: oops yes you're right. but ignoring this part, my question still remains...

Answer (score 1):

Since $M$ is a square matrix, it has linearly independent columns if and only if it is invertible, which happens only if $J$ is the zero matrix.

Indeed, the product $J^\dagger J$ is the orthogonal projection onto $(\ker J)^\perp$, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Projectors). Hence, $M$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\ker J$. So, the columns of $M$ span $\ker J$. But selecting the minimal spanning set of columns is still a task up to you.

Also, I don't think it's a good idea to compute $J^\dagger$ just to find a basis for $\ker M$. [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28linear_algebra%29#Basis) takes less work.